# Case when in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, iif

I am trying to identify some rows using IIF and Not IN operator but I get syntax error. I want to identify the rows where none of the column contain A1 and A2 using the below query. I don't get the desired results. Any help much appreciated and thank you in advance.

Table: (Note: There are upto 16 variables/Columns in original table)

```
ID  KH1 KH2 KH3 KH4 KH5 KH6

001 A2  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1
002 F1  A1  B1  D1  E1  G1
003 A1  B1  D1  E1  
004 XX  XX  XX  XX  XX  XX
005 AA  AB  AC  A2  XX
006 XX  XX  XX  A1  
007 XX  XX  XX  XX  A1  XX
008 XX  XX  AE  XX  XX  AC
```

Output:

```
ID  KH1 KH2 KH3 KH4 KH5 KH6 Identified

001 A2  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1  No
002 F1  A1  B1  D1  E1  G1  No
003 XX  B1  D1  E1          Yes     
005 AA  AB  AC  A2  XX      Yes
006 XX  XX  XX  A1          No
007 XX  XX  XX  XX  A1  XX  No
```

My Query

```
Select * from Table
IIF (((Nz([KH1],' ')) Not in ('A1', 'A2')) AND ((Nz([KH2],' ')) Not in ('A1', 'A2')) AND ((Nz([KH3],' ')) Not in ('A1', 'A2')) AND ((Nz([KH4],' ')) Not in ('A1', 'A2')) AND ((Nz([KH5],' ')) Not in ('A1', 'A2')) AND ((Nz([KH6],' ')) Not in ('A1', 'A2')));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`IIF()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) function in your code is missing the *truepart* and the *elsepart*:

```
SELECT *,
  IIF (    Nz([KH1], '') NOT IN ('A1', 'A2') 
       AND Nz([KH2], '') NOT IN ('A1', 'A2')
       AND Nz([KH3], '') NOT IN ('A1', 'A2')
       AND Nz([KH4], '') NOT IN ('A1', 'A2')
       AND Nz([KH5], '') NOT IN ('A1', 'A2')
       AND Nz([KH6], '') NOT IN ('A1', 'A2'),
       'Yes',
       'No'
  ) AS Identified
FROM tablename;
```

Or:

```
SELECT *,
  IIF (   Nz([KH1], '') IN ('A1', 'A2') 
       OR Nz([KH2], '') IN ('A1', 'A2')
       OR Nz([KH3], '') IN ('A1', 'A2')
       OR Nz([KH4], '') IN ('A1', 'A2')
       OR Nz([KH5], '') IN ('A1', 'A2')
       OR Nz([KH6], '') IN ('A1', 'A2'),
       'No',
       'Yes'
  ) AS Identified
FROM tablename;
```

Comment: Note that Access allows logicals (booleans) in the `SELECT` part, so the `IIF`, `TruePart` and `ElsePart` can be omitted, and Access will return -1 for True and 0 for False. Using `IIF` is more portable, though, since some RDBMSes (SQL server in particular) don't support logicals in the `SELECT` part.

Answer (score 1):

Try below Query

```
SELECT MyTable.*,  
IIf([KH1] In ('A1','A2'),"No",
IIf([KH2] In ('A1','A2'),"No",
IIf([KH3] In ('A1','A2'),"No",
IIf([KH4] In ('A1','A2'),"No",
IIf([KH5] In ('A1','A2'),"No",
IIf([KH6] In ('A1','A2'),"No","Yes")))))) AS Identified
FROM MyTable;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried the same code somehow I get some syntax error, I have checked multiple times I didn't make any mistake, only thing is I have 16 variables. at 14th variable IIF syntax it shows error. But the code is without any error, I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Can you share a sample copy of db via google drive or dropbox for checking.

Comment: Hi, Sure I can, please provide your Id.

Comment: @KCApril Upload to google drive and then post the downloadable link here in comment.

Comment: @KCApril allow to view or download.

Comment: Yes, I provided the permissions. Are you able to download?

Comment: Yes. IIF have nesting limitation. May 13 nested IIF can be used same time and you have more than 13 nested IIF and that is causing warning. Have to find some other way or have to use VBA custom function.

Comment: Do you know an alternative in SQL query or VBA? please let me know